# Efficient way to get the included items in a restricted table by SQL inside MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following 2 tables.

```
CREATE TABLE `media_scores` (
  `media_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `sorting_score` float unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `date_added` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `date_updated` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`media_id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `media_restrict` (
  `media_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `restrict_type` enum('exclude','include') NOT NULL,
  `country_code` char(2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`media_id`,`restrict_type`,`countryCode`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Table Media_scores holds media_ids with specific scores.
Table Media_restrict restricts a media according to country code. If there are no restriction then the media_id is global. If it was the restrict_type of excluded it will regard that media to be global except for the region specified (multiple country can be excluded). If its restrict_type is include then only the region specified can view the media_id. (multiple country can be included)

This is my SQL so far

```
SELECT ms.* 
FROM media_scores as ms 
LEFT JOIN media_restrict as mr on mr.media_id = ms.media_id 
WHERE ( (mr.media_id is null) OR (mr.restrict_type = 'exclude' and mr.country_code != 'CA') OR (mr.restrict_type = 'include' and mr.country_code = 'CA')
```

So for each case, I thought each OR will take care of the condition necessary so that when Left join, It will only select those who's media should display, however due to multiple region being entered for a given media, im stumped with my query as there are some media_ids that should be excluded that shows up.

I hope I have given sufficient information. Let me know if you need more.

**UPDATE**
Here are the tables and output expected

media_scores

```
+----------+---------------+-------------+--------------+
| media_id | sorting_score | date_added  | date_updated |
+----------+---------------+-------------+--------------+
|        1 |           25  | 2014-11-05  | 0000-00-00   |
|       2  |           16  | 2014-11-05  | 0000-00-00   |
|       3  |           33  | 2014-11-05  | 0000-00-00   |
|       4  |           11  | 2014-11-04  | 0000-00-00   |
+----------+---------------+-------------+--------------+
```

media_restrict

```
+----------+---------------+--------------+
| media_id | restrict_type | country_code |
+----------+---------------+--------------+
|        1 | exclude       | US           |
|        1 | exclude       | UK           |
|        2 | include       | US           |
|        2 | include       | CA           |
|        3 | include       | CN           |
+----------+---------------+--------------+
```

If I put in the query as country_code US

then output would be:

```
+----------+---------------+------------+--------------+
| media_id | sorting_score | date_added | date_updated |
+----------+---------------+------------+--------------+
|        2 |            16 | 2014-11-05 | 0000-00-00   |
|       4  |            11 | 2014-11-04 | 0000-00-00   |
+----------+---------------+------------+--------------+
```

IF I put in the query as country_code CN

```
+----------+---------------+------------+--------------+
| media_id | sorting_score | date_added | date_updated |
+----------+---------------+------------+--------------+
|        1 |            25 | 2014-11-05 | 0000-00-00   |
|        3 |            33 | 2014-11-05 | 0000-00-00   |
|       4  |            11 | 2014-11-04 | 0000-00-00   |
+----------+---------------+------------+--------------+
```

If I put in the query country_code as CA

```
+----------+---------------+------------+--------------+
| media_id | sorting_score | date_added | date_updated |
+----------+---------------+------------+--------------+
|        1 |            25 | 2014-11-05 | 0000-00-00   |
|        2 |            16 | 2014-11-05 | 0000-00-00   |
|       4  |            11 | 2014-11-04 | 0000-00-00   |
+----------+---------------+------------+--------------+
```

Comment: Please edit your question with sample data and desired results.

Comment: I think, all you need is to move the `(mr.restrict_type = 'exclude' and mr.country_code != 'CA') OR (mr.restrict_type = 'include' and mr.country_code = 'CA')` condition from your `WHERE` clause to the `ON` clause, and get rid of the whole clause `WHERE ( (mr.media_id is null)`

Answer (score 1):

SELECT ms.*

FROM media_scores as ms

LEFT OUTER JOIN media_restrict AS mr

ON ms.media_id = mr.media_id and mr.restrict_type = 'exclude' and mr.country_code = 'CA'

> excluding 'exclude' media with 'WHERE mr.media_id IS NULL'

LEFT OUTER JOIN media_restrict AS mr2

ON ms.media_id = mr2.media_id AND mr2.restrict_type = 'include' AND mr2.country_code = 'CA'

> join for 'include' choosen region

LEFT OUTER JOIN media_restrict AS mr3

ON ms.media_id = mr3.media_id AND mr3.restrict_type = 'include' AND mr3.country_code != 'CA'

> join for excluding 'include' not choosen region

WHERE mr.media_id IS NULL AND

(CASE mr2.media_id WHEN ms.media_id THEN NULL ELSE mr3.media_id END) IS NULL;

> if some medias 'include' is another region, mr3 data is not null.
>   but both choosen, not choosen region is included also mr3 not null.
>   because i joining mr2 and use case clause.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly the restrict level is defined for the media. It can be one of those:

- exclude
- include
- global

In this case you first need to construct a query that has this type at the media_score level, like this:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT ms.*, COALESCE(t.type, 'global') as type
  FROM media_scores as ms
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT media_id, max(restrict_type) as type
    FROM media_restrict 
    GROUP BY media_id
    ) t ON t.media_id = ms.media_id
) mst
```

In fact, I believe your tables should have been designed this way the first place, i.e. the `restrict_type` should have been in the `media_scores` table

The idea is to create a view `mst` that has a type there, like this:

```
CREATE VIEW t AS (
    SELECT media_id, max(restrict_type) as type
    FROM media_restrict 
    GROUP BY media_id
    );

CREATE VIEW mst AS (
  SELECT ms.*, COALESCE(t.type, 'global') as type
  FROM media_scores as ms
  LEFT JOIN t ON t.media_id = ms.media_id
);
```

When you have this view you can then apply your conditions. unfortunately, SQLFiddle is not playing nicely right now and I cannot test it.

Then the resulting query will be a combination of three SELECT queries combined with a UNION ALL clause:

```
select mst.* 
from mst 
INNER JOIN media_restrict mr 
ON mst.media_id = mr.media_id
AND mst.type = 'include' AND mr.country_code = 'CA'
UNION ALL
select mst.* 
from mst 
WHERE mst.type = 'exclude' AND
NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM media_restrict mr 
            WHERE mr.media_id = mst.media_id AND mr.country_code = 'CA')
UNION ALL
select mst.* 
from mst 
WHERE mst.type = 'global';
```

Please test it and let us know how it goes.

Update: the SQL Fiddle started to work again. [Check it](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/46dbe/6) out

Comment: you union 3 times which means im tripling up the speed of the query.

Comment: If you check the actual query each of the sub-queries work with a subset of the whole data. The first one uses 'included' media, the second one 'excluded', the third one 'global'. As I said in my answer you would be better off having the type in the media_scores table. That way you could have the index in the column which would make the queries run faster

Comment: so your solution is to actually move the restriction type over and add global as a type. If thats the case where is the country_code going to reside? are we shifting that too? If so then you have a flat table in the end, which you must include the combination that you need.

Comment: No, I did not suggest that. I just said that if the media_id is can have one type there is no reason to have it in a restrict table. The restrict table will have just that: the restricts by countries. If you have a look at my final query I do not use the restrict_type from the media_restrict anymore, as the type is driven by the media_score. If it is too late to change the table structure then you are stuck with this design unfortunately. MySQL does not support materialised views, so these queries will not be efficient

Comment: I will take your suggestion into consideration and benchmark it. tks.